# What to do with all the books?

Tags: starfield

There are many books to collect in Starfield.

**What can you do with all the books?**

Do we have any benefit if we collect them all? Or can we just sell the books in the Bookshop in Akila?

Comment: Note: Magazines give buffs and the books don't, see https://starfield.fandom.com/wiki/Skill_Magazines_and_Books

Comment: What I usually do is *not pick them up*

Comment: Dominoes, obviously

Comment: Asking for a mod recommendation is off-topic here, you may want to consider removing that part

Comment: @pinckerman - Could you please show me the ruleset where asking for a mod is off-topic?

Comment: From community-specific reasons to close: "Questions that ask for recommendations of games, servers, software, or hardware are off topic.", and a mod is a software.

Comment: @TimmyJim How else would you read them? :D

Comment: @PeterCo Mod recommendation questions are actually allowed in Arqade as per community consensus in the meta posts: [Closed 'mod recommendation' question… can it be improved and then reopened?](//meta.arqade.com/q/5547) & [Is “mod rec” really an umbrella category that we want to use?…](//meta.arqade.com/q/6828) In this case, you have to ask it in a separate question to avoid getting this question closed. Reword your separate question to ask for any solution instead of asking about a mod specifically. This is because some may see it as a recommendation question and vote to close it as off-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of special books which, when read, make landmarks discoverable.

- The Pyramids of Giza – Read the book The Ancient Civilization of Egypt found in Sinclair’s books at Akila City
- Empire State Building – Read the book Our Lost Heritage found in the President’s office at MAST headquarters in New Atlantis
- US Bank Tower – Read the book Hope Family Tree in Director Ron Hope’s office at the HopeTech’s headquarters on Hopetown, a city in the Valo system on the planet Polvo
- The Shanghai Tower – Read the book Essentials of Modern Macroeconomics on ship around Porimma II
- Burj Khalifa – Read the book Race to the Heavens found in a VIP room at Siren of the Stars
- International Commerce Center – Read the book Maurice Lyon’s journal in the New Homestead settlement museum on Titan
- The Gateway Arch – Read the book The Price of Destiny found in Benjamin Bayu’s penthouse on Neon (you may need Theft skill to pickpocket Bayu)
- Abeno Harukas – Read the Diary of Kyosuke Nagata in the Lock Prison on the Crimson’s Fleet’s Suvorov planet in the Kryx system
- The Shard – Read the book Oliver Twist also found at Sinclair’s Books in Akila City

As mentioned in the comments, there are also magazines which once collected will give a permanent improvement to your character.

There are quite a few, so I'll put the link the comments mentioned https://starfield.fandom.com/wiki/Skill_Magazines_and_Books

Answer (score 2):

Books generally have no use. Selling them to a bookstore is the best way to get the most from them, though some characters like Cora (Sam's daughter) have interest in books. You can also sell them to a few others. There's no specific use of books, unless you're a collector.

Comment: Interestingly enough, while Cora will ask you for books, you can't actually give any to her :(